# Gratuitous changing of keyboard layout/input method

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I thought I had posted on this some time ago, but four different search strings failed to find the question.

Some time ago, my system was frequently changing my input method without warning to Greek. After a few days of tolerating this annoyance, it started trying to force me to use Chinese instead.  After several more days, an O.S. update made it stop.  It has remained on the one I use most for some time.

But today, it has changed to Korean several times.  **Every time** I unlock (open the MacBook Pro) it is set to Korean.  And when I rebooted and logged in this morning, it was on Korean.  (It was set to my preferred keyboard when I shut down.)  At least once, it changed while I was using the MBP.

Since it happens at either logout or login and between physical closing and opening, I do not believe it is from accidentally hitting the shortcut for switching.  (Plus, if my clumsiness were doing that, it would have been happening yesterday.)

It's also not caused by software update: the last update ws in November,  I am about to install 14.2.1.  I hope that will fix it, but **it would be nice to know the cause and/or fix for the next time it occurs.**

Comment: Not only did the update not fix it, it reduced my screen brightness from 100% to about 30%.  GRRR.  (Not the first time an O.S. update has irritatingly changed settings.)